# How to solve GGX roughness from existing maps

Tags: brdf, ggx, photometric

I have a problem that I cannot really wrap my head around.

I have a minimal light stage setup to scan heads:

I have cross polarized cameras and parallel polarized cameras.
I have parallel polarized LEDs
I capture k-frames and tracking frames
I am able to:

- calculate normals and color albedos from Photometric Stereo (Woodham)
- calculate a mesh via Photogrammetry
- project normals, albedo and appearance on the mesh
- create a reflectance map (via parallel - cross)
  Does anybody have a tip?

Thank you for your time!